# How can I make a jlabel highlight when a mouse pointer is pointing at it in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Java NetBeans.  I don't have that much of experience in programming.  I am trying to make a label highlight when I point a mouse pointer on it.

I tried: `Properties > events > mouse > focus gained`.

Comment: [How to write a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). Remember, `JLabel` is, by default transparent, so you may need to use `setOpaque`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the Label -> Events -> Mouse -> MouseEntered

Add this code.

```
private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{                                     
    jLabel1.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel1.setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

Right click the Label -> Events -> Mouse -> MouseExited

Add this code.

```
private void jLabel1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    jLabel1.setBackground(Color.white);
    jLabel1.setOpaque(false);
}
```